# Does there exist a space which has trivial fundamental group but is not path connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, geometric-topology

I am asking this because the definition of space X to be simply connected is that X is path connected and has trivial fundamental group. I am not able to understand the importance of space X to be path connected in this definition.

Comment: If a space is not path connected then it does not really have a fundamental group, but rather a fundamental groupoid (since the choice of a basepoint becomes important).

Comment: Right. The point of requiring $X$ to be path connected is so that we don't need to specify a basepoint when talking about its fundamental group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assumption of path-connectivity in the definition of simple-connectedness is one of convenience, for two reasons.

1. As mentioned, this makes the identification of the fundamental group independent of choice of basepoint (necessary for its construction), up to isomorphism.  Since working up to isomorphism is "good enough" for 99% of algebraic arguments, this is a convenient thing to do.
2. Once you get further along you will see how to use constructs called *covering spaces* and *fiber bundles* which are quite powerful.  Some of the technical theorems require certain niceness of the spaces or basepoints involved, and assuming path-connectedness either makes things nice or makes the ugliness manageable so that you still get your theorem.

And, to answer the question in your title, take any two simply-connected spaces $X$ and $Y$ and form their disjoint union $X \amalg Y$.  The result is not path-connected, but for any choice of basepoint $z_0$ we have $\pi_1(X \amalg Y, z_0)$ trivial.  For a concrete instance, consider the union of two (distinct) parallel lines in the Euclidean plane, with the ordinary subspace topology

Comment: To those who study automorphisms of fundamental groups, 99% seems a bit much :-<

Answer (score 1):

Yes such spaces exist. One example which can be found in Munkres Topology 2nd Edition is the dictionary order topology (Example 2, p. 85) on the unit square (Example 3, p. 90). This is an example of a space that is connected: if it were the disjoint union of two open sets, then the interval [a,b] would be too. But this space is not path connected (the only path connected components of it are the vertical intervals).

It thus has trivial fundamental group, since $\pi_1(X,x_0) \simeq \pi_1(I)$ where $I$ denotes the interval $[0,1]$.

Topology is full of counterexamples. There's an entire book of them: *Counterexamples in Topology* Steen & Seebach (1995).

In the case of simple connectedness, part of the reason for the path-connected assumption is to rule out pathological spaces such as the one above.

Comment: At the OP's present stage in studying topology, a simpler counterexample is likely to be more useful; I'd suggests a two-point space with the discrete topology.  The "Counterexamples ..." book is likely to become useful at a later stage.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, while I agree that the Counterexamples book is not particularly useful in studying topology, my point in mentioning it is that counterexamples are frequent enough in the field that definitions are often constructed to avoid them (e.g. the second-countable and Hausdorff conditions on manifolds are often explained as omitting the "long line" and the line with two origins). Munkres' Topology book goes through the dictionary order topology well before any discussion of the fundamental group, so I'd argue that the counterexample itself is not too complicated.